# How find row by exact much of joined rows with SQL?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

```
parent:
   ╔════╦══════╗
   ║ id ║ name ║
   ╠════╬══════╣
   ║ 1  ║ A    ║
   ║ 2  ║ B    ║
   ║ 3  ║ A    ║
   ║ 4  ║ A    ║
   ║ 5  ║ A    ║
   ╚════╩══════╝
child:
   ╔════╦═══════════╦══════╗
   ║ id ║ parent_id ║ name ║
   ╠════╬═══════════╬══════╣
   ║ 1  ║     1     ║  a   ║
   ║ 2  ║     1     ║  b   ║
   ║ 3  ║     2     ║  a   ║
   ║ 4  ║     2     ║  b   ║
   ║ 5  ║     3     ║  a   ║
   ║ 6  ║     4     ║  a   ║
   ║ 7  ║     4     ║  c   ║
   ║ 8  ║     5     ║  a   ║
   ║ 9  ║     5     ║  b   ║
   ║ 10 ║     5     ║  c   ║
   ╚════╩═══════════╩══════╝
```

I want to find specific row from *parent* table with name **A** which have exact two related rows in *child* table with names **a** and **b**.
In example table is only one row is suitable (with id = 1).

Row with id = 2 is not suitable because name of parent is **B**. Row with id = 3 is not suitable because it has only one child. Row with id = 4 is not suitable because one of childs has name **c**. Row with id = 5 is not suitable because it has one unnecessary child with name **c**.

Help me please write SQL query to find row from parent table with any number of specified childs. Thank you

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: What if there is a row with children a,b and c?

Comment: @forpas no, this row is not suitable too

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, `group by` the id of the parent and use `group_concat()` (for MySql or an equivalent function for other databases) in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select p.id
from parent p join child c
on c.parent_id = p.id
group by p.id
having group_concat(c.name order by c.name) = 'a,b';
```

I assume there are no duplicate combinations of `(parent_id, name)` in the table `child`. If there are then change to:

```
having group_concat(distinct c.name order by c.name) = 'a,b';
```

You will have to provide a sorted comma separated list like `'a,b'` to specify the children that you search for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
select p.id
from parent p join
     child c
     on p.id = c.parentid
where p.name = 'A'
group by p.id
having count(*) = 2 and
       min(c.name) = 'a' and max(c.name) = 'b';
```

Comment: Thank you, good option. But maybe you can generalize your solution to find parent row with any number of childs?